# Intune PowerShell script to copy files to client machines

Tags: powershell, intune

Have been struggling with this for last few weeks. Any advice will be an immense help. From Intune I'm with a Intune PSScript trying to copy a file to the all the client machines in a particular group in the domain.

If it works the script will copy the files from a shared network location to `C:\ProgramData\etc\etc` in the client machines in System context. It is continuously failing but if I run the script on the client machine as an admin it works perfectly fine. In Intune it says 'Failed'.

Script:

```
Copy-Item "C:\networkshare\etc\etc" -Destination "C:\ProgramData\etc\etc"
```

Can you let me know if I'm missing something?

Comment: I haven't used Intune yet but one idea would be to wrap the `Copy-Item` in an `Invoke-Command` using the `-Credential` parameter. You may have to figure out a way to more securely store this credential which I can thinks of two with examples if you ask me back, but run this way to confirm `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Copy-Item "C:\networkshare\etc\etc" -Destination "C:\ProgramData\etc\etc" } -Credential (Get-Credential);`. If it works then your network share (I assume `\\servername\networkshare\etc\etc`) will be accessible by the credential. Otherwise I think it uses `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.

Comment: @BitcoinMurderousManiac, thanks for your reply. I will definitely try this and will get back to you with the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to package everything into a win32 app and deploy it to the endpoints. In the package, you will include the files and a PS script that copies the files to the specified location. Then you will execute this at the system context.
Inform me if you need any more details.